# Is the USB B connector still standard?

Tags: usb, standard

Nowadays, There are several kinds of USB connectors for USB connection.

- A type
- B type
- micro-B
- mini-B
- USB C
- Etc.

The connector sizes are gradually smaller than before. It is a big advantage because it reduces board size.

But the B type connector is more suitable for a big size product because it is very easy to connect the plug. But I rarely see the B type connectors now.

- Is the B type connector is removed from the standard?
- Can I make a product by using the B type connector?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I see them alot on instrument type things. Debuggers, protocol analyzers, USB oscilloscopes or data loggers and such like.

Comment: Yeah, USB-B makes perfect sense on big bulky devices. Imagine if your printer used micro-USB, you could easily destroy the connector by tripping over the cable or pulling it the wrong way. I don't know if it's been deprecated or anything though.

Comment: You can download the USB standard from USB IF whenever you like, and check for yourself.

Comment: Total Phase products use USB-B and so do LabJack and Picoscope. So, I think  you are safe to use it.

Comment: Technically the title should ask about USB 2.0 Type-B connector, not just "USB-B", because there are well-defined (and ugly) USB 3.0 connectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB B connector is still part of the USB standard, "filo" is correct. All USB revisions (including latest revision of USB standard, USB 3.2) include backward compatibility with USB 2.0, the general packet-based framework remains the same, and all legacy cable assemblies (which includes USB 2.0 Type-B connector) are fully specified.

The new revision of USB standard only splits the legacy cable drawings and definitions into a separate document (from USB 3.2 specs, Section 5 page 50):

> The electro-mechanical definition and requirements for USB connectors
>   and cables have been removed from this specification and are now
>   located in the [**USB 3.1 Legacy Cable and Connector specification**](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-31-legacy-cable-and-connector-revision-10).

The exception is the set of mini connectors, mini-A. mini-B, and mini-AB receptacle, which was retired from USB 2.0 specifications, and superseded by flimsy micro-A-B set of connectors. So using mini-B won't lead to USB-IF certification logo, but the old-style USB 2.0 Type-B receptacle is still a valid design option.

CLARIFICATION: USB 3.2 Specifications state, Section 3, page 15

> USB 3.2 is a dual-bus architecture that provides backward
>   compatibility with USB 2.0. One bus is a USB 2.0 bus (see Universal
>   Serial Bus Specification, Revision 2.0)

Formally it means that all USB 2.0 provisions, with all ECNs are still in effect, including all connector arrangements.

AMPLIFICATION: More formally, USB electro-mechanical connectivity nowadays is defined in the [USB Type-C specifications](https://cambrionix.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/USB-Type-C-Specification-Release-1.3.pdf). The Type-C specs define backward compatibility by specifying "legacy cable assemblies" like "USB 2.0 Standard-B to Type-C", which implies that there must be USB 2.0 Standard-B receptacles to work with. A USB device can be made with Standard USB 2 B receptacle, the only downside is that it can't claim "USB 3.x compatibility", it is a "USB 2.0 device", with all corresponding USB 2.0 certifications/implications.

Comment: The document you linked to is the one I based my answer on. There are only 3 references to 2.0 type B in it, all in the context of backward compatibility of 3.1 sockets. Also 3.1 compliance document does not mention 2.0 connector certification at all. The fact that new sockets are backward compatible with old plugs does not make old sockets valid design option. Only the eligibility of the device for certification does. Unfortunately I could not find any positive confirmation on the eligibility

Comment: Just saw latest updates in your answer. It is interesting that you mention legacy assembly as proof that USB 2.0 B is still OK, and say that mini-B is not OK, even though legacy Type C to both Micro-B and Mini-B assemblies are defined in the same table of compliant cables.

Comment: @Maple, the difference is that mini-connectors were officially retired, while USB 2.0 Type-B were not. The announcement was, however, in a bit odd manner, through business release, see  https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20070417005149/en/USB-IF-Refines-USB-2.0-On-The-Go-Spec-Smaller . The only reference to mini-connectors replacement with "micro" is in "On-The-Go Supplement to the USB 2.0 Specification" rev 1.3, in document revision section. The whole thing is still inconsistent, since it says that mini-B stays, while no cables with mini ends were eligible for certifications. Go figure.

Answer (score 4):

1. Yes - USB B connector is still part of the standard.
2. Yes - you can design a device with USB B connector if you have enough space. You can also design a device with any other connector carrying USB signals. If you use non-standard connector you probably can't claim that the device is fully USB-compliant, certify it easily or can't put the USB logos on it.

Comment: "USB B connector is still part of the standard" Which standard?

Comment: @Maple the USB standard I guess

Comment: @valerio_new There are **6** of them. Guess better.

Comment: @Maple in usb 3.0 you have the 5 additional pins. In usb 3.1 you have the type c and the ones from usb 3.0. In usb 2.0, which afaik is still valid, you have the old 4 pin usb B

Comment: @valerio_new You don't need to explain that to me. And since you know that much, you should realize that your first comment above was basically pointless. Now, _parts_ of 2.0 have been specifically deprecated by 3.0. Type B hasn't been, but that does not make it "part" of 3.0/3.1 standards, as stated in the answer. My comment was meant to point out this inconsistency. And BTW, in 3.0 you have either 5 or 7 additional pins.

Comment: @Maple oh i didn't see your answer, now it is clear :)

Comment: @valerio_new I am glad we sorted this out :) The biggest question, however, if whether or not USB IF considers not explicitly deprecated parts of old standards still "standard". For example, will they allow you to use USB logo on a device with Micro B socket? That's the question I could not find an answer to anywhere

Comment: @Maple, Micro-B receptacle is employed in billions of smartphones. You probably mean "mini-B". This is a good question. But if you are concerned with certification, you must be a USB-IF member, and if you are a member, you can request official clarification by e-mail through "member login".

Answer (score 2):

> Is the B type connector is removed from the standard?

The old Type B **receptacle is superseded** by "USB 3.1 Standard-B Receptacle" and "USB 3.1 Powered-B Receptacle". The new receptacles are backwards-compatible with old Type B plugs, so technically Type B is not "removed", since its **plug is still supported** somewhat.

However neither of two new USB 3.1 type B plugs can be inserted into old Type B receptacle. Furthermore, no cable assemblies with old Type B plug are allowed by 3.1 standard, which means Type B socket is deprecated de facto.

> Can I make a product by using the B type connector?

Now, this is different. I did not find any 3.0/3.1 documents on Type B certification. To me this looks like any new device with Type B receptacle **will not be certified** as USB 3.0 compliant. I don't know whether or not it can still be certified as USB 2.0 compliant device.

Comment: [Here](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/cabconn_legacy_3_1_compliance_rev_1_1.pdf)'s a document which mentions certification for USB B connector.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Could you point out the paragraph? All I found there is certification for **USB 3.1** standard/powered B connectors

Comment: Wrong answer, -1

Comment: @Ale..chenski I was wondering when you show up and set things straight :)

Comment: Glad to be of service :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's still used. A lot of USB audio equipment uses it, even today, even in new products, because the impression that the cables are better quality than usb mini or micro cables. Some audiophiles even believe that the B cables sound better, although I doubt there's much actual evidence to support that belief.

Comment: It's insane what things some hardcore "audiophiles" are imagining. Once they bought that 50$ ultra quality gold finished extra thick and pretty looking USB cable, they just don't want to hear that the money was wasted ;)

Comment: @Rev1.0, actually, in old era when audio data were transmitted via "isochronous FS data streams", without any corrections via retry of packets, just skipping corrupted packets, the quality and shielding of USB cables might make some difference. Nowadays the high-end USB audio uses bulk HS transfers, with guaranteed quality of delivery even over depressed-quality connections.

Comment: I'm super confused when I bought a midi keyboard online, receiving it yesterday to find it with a type-B jack. I've basically expelled all other connectors and am living with solely type-C (though the variety in completeness of implementation is painful) for a while now, and it pissed me off that they the keyboard company didn't even seem to consider micro- or mini-. And everyday I hear HIFI-heads around me claiming 'you can't listen if not using monocrystalline analog cable' and stuff, so yeah. Consumerism more toxic than the Internet.